# Get types used inside C# method body- MonoCelil

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, mono

Can anyone help me getting a list of a specific type used inside a C# method body?

I see it is possible on another therad - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741770/2593501

I am new in Mono.cecil. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thnaks 
Sudip

Comment: what do you mean specific type? do you mean type of object? use typeof(Object)

Comment: i want to know, inside a method body, how many times, object o=new object(); has been used.

Comment: You can't do this: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2693922/298754

Comment: I see, Mono Cecil can do this. Any help on this is appreciated.