# Given a managed assembly, and a type in it, how to reflect on the type to check if any of its methods call a given method?

Tags: c#, .net

How may I reflect a type to check if it has any method in it that calls, say, the `InterlockedExchange.Compare` method?

My guess is that it's not possible using simply reflection. I might need to use Roslyn or Mono.Cecil.

```
private static bool HasOneOrMoreMethodsThatCallInterlockedExchangeCompare(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    }

    if (!type.IsClass) return false;

    var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        var methodBody = method.GetMethodBody();

        // This is where I need help
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Eser Why is it a poor question? I know reflection and I know that it's not possible using reflection. I am trying to get a confirmation that it isn't and to find out what else to use. It's not as easy a question as it appears.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693922/2193020) would seem to be confirmation that it's not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Look if a method is called inside a method using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741350/look-if-a-method-is-called-inside-a-method-using-reflection) - although this might be out-of-date. The top answer does have a code snippet that looks like it does exactly what you want though.

Comment: @Eser As you can see with the answer that hnefati linked to also, that answer also air brushes the issue. A very specific answer to my question would be enormously helpful to everyone. It's not as simple as it seems to be.

Comment: So why not place a bounty on the existing question?

Comment: You have to decompile the IL.  Sure, there are libraries for that, like Mono.Cecil.  You still don't know if it is going to actually happen, the call might appear inside an if-statement.  You can't solve that Halting Problem.

Comment: Is what you want, Find All References?

Comment: It should be possible, ildasm does not perform any magic. I found a pretty old codeproject article, https://www.codeproject.com/articles/14058/parsing-the-il-of-a-method-body. This may not work on more recent versions, give it a shot.