# Reflection to find wether a method is using any particular method or not

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a dll which has some classes, these classes have some methods.
And some of those methods has another method call inside it.

How can I check whether a method inside a class has a specific method or not.
I have done some googling on this and I was able to find the classes inside the dll as follows:

```
public List < string > GetClassFromDlLstring(string dllName)
{
    Assembly assemblies = null;
    try
    {
        assemblies = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    var allTypes = assemblies.GetTypes();

    return (from allType in allTypes where allType.IsClass select allType.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

And similarly a method to find all the methods inside a class as follows:

```
public List <string> GetAllTMethodClass(string dllName, string className)
{
    var assemblies = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllName);

    Type type = assemblies.GetType(className);

    var temp = new List <string> ();

    try
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods();
        //MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach(MethodInfo meth in methods)
        {
            if (meth.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method && meth.MemberType != MemberTypes.Property) 
                temp.Add(meth.Name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return temp;
}
```

I have a problem now the function above return property name also.
Further I want to go through the function list and check weather the function contain a particular function or not. How can I achieve this?

### Edit 1:

I found the similar post whose link is below
 - [Look if a method is called inside a method using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741350/look-if-a-method-is-called-inside-a-method-using-reflection)
 - [Get types used inside a C# method body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667816/get-types-used-inside-c-sharp-method-body/5668079#5668079)

Answer (score 4):

You have to look into method's IL. IMO, [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you provide me some link?